# SAXParseException using Python and suds 0.4?

Tags: python, soap, suds

I have a simple Python script that uses Suds to pull data from a SOAP web service.  It works perfectly on one machine, but when I move it to another that has an older version of Python (2.4.3), I get the following stack trace:

```
>>> client = suds.client.Client(url, username='xxx', password='xxx', location=service_location, cache=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
File "/home/etlsmart/lib/python2.4/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/reader.py", line 152, in open
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/reader.py", line 79, in open
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/reader.py", line 101, in download
File "/home/etlsmart/lib/python2.4/site-packages/suds/sax/parser.py", line 136, in parse
    sax.parse(source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/_xmlplus/sax/expatreader.py", line 109, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/_xmlplus/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/_xmlplus/sax/expatreader.py", line 220, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/_xmlplus/sax/handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:18:2: mismatched tag
```

I've looked at various related errors involving the cache, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.  I've disabled the cache and /tmp/suds only contained a version file in any case.

Is this likely related to the Python version or is there something else obvious that I should try?

Comment: Well, I've upgraded python to 2.7.1 and get the same error so it's something else in the environment.  Any suggestions where to look would be most appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so I've found the problem and it was a combination of stupidity and bad assumptions on my part (if there's really a difference between the two).  When I moved to the second box it was on a different network segment.  Because of that, instead of talking to the web server, I was talking to a firewall who was asking me to authenticate.  I found this by stepping through in the debugger, but for anyone having a similar problem, you could do something like 'print buffer' after line 121 in xml/sax/xmlreader.py just to be sure it is well-formed xml.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. The server has answering HTML instead of SOAP.

The endpoint has responding with an HTML message of error, not an SOAP XML. For some reason, SUDS says "I cannot parse this. Halp!" instead of "I cannot parse this answer: < answer here >", even with DEBUG log level.

Found that poking into suds.reader, using a debugger:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py in download(self, url)
    100         content = ctx.document
    101         sax = Parser()
--> 102         return sax.parse(string=content)
    103 
    104     def cache(self):
```

Look at `content`and see if its an SOAP XML.

Good luck.

Comment: Same problem here. Specifically, I forgot to append "?WSDL" to the end of a SOAP endpoint URL, which caused it to return HTML instead of SOAP XML, like you said.

Comment: I keep running into this problem intermittently. The problem finally went away after i saved the WSDL file locally and referenced it with a `file:` URI. Granted this defeats the whole point of WSDL and may not be an option for everybody but it's an acceptable solution for my use case.

Comment: It can also happen if user is not authorized.